# Meaning of "go to!" as an (old) exclamation

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm reading (well listening to an audio book really) Ivanhoe (19th century) and there are some old expressions and words that have rather fallen out of modern use. Most of them I can google, but the phrase "go to!" is kind of hard, since it's part of normal modern speech and is even part of some expressions.

It seems to be used to express some irritation with the one you say it to. But sometimes it feels like it's more closely related to "go on" (as in "continue"). One example would be the following passages:

> "These truces with the infidels," he exclaimed, without caring how suddenly he interrupted the stately Templar, "make an old man of me!"
>
> "Go to, knave, how so?" said Cedric, his features prepared to receive favourably the expected jest.

--

> "The foul fiend take Malvoisin," answered the Saxon, "and his keeper both! I will teach them that the wood was disforested in terms of the Forest Charter. But enough of this. Go to, knave, go to thy place - and thou, Gurth, get thee another dog, [...]"

Comment: It roughly means *get to the point*. See meaning 6: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_to

Comment: @Anonym "to express protest or surprise; 'come, now!'" This mostly makes sense, but it feels kind of off for the second quote. I guess it can have different nuances?

Comment: I think that in the second quote *go to* is simply truncated from *go to thy place*. Keep in mind that the *to* in *go to* is a actually an adverb meaning *to the end, to the fullest extent, completely*. It is generally archaic now, but we still use it in a select few phrases like *the door slammed to*.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fitting definition in the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go-to):

> *archaic* Said to express disbelief, impatience, or admonition.

Answer (score 1):

The user that quoted from Oxford Dictionary is right. However I suspect the phrase was more nuanced than that. It's a highly idiomatic phrase (chiefly British) and has long fallen out of fashion and use. When used in the sorts of context you excerpted I believe it was a euphemistic way of telling someone to "go to hell." The connotation is much stronger, however, and in our modern parlance the phrase would be closer to telling someone to "f*** off." Notice how in your second excerpt the Saxon tells the knave to "go to, go to *thy place*." So "go to" is a shortened way of telling someone to "go somewhere," and that fact combined with the definition of the phrase as an expression of impatience or admonition makes me suspect makes me suspect "somewhere" is generally understood as hell.

Comment: In the first quote there's not really any hostility though. Cedric (the saxon) is eagerly awaiting the punch line of a joke from his favourite jester. Granted, Cedric is a bit of a hothead, but I don't think he'd tell Wamba (the fool) to "go to hell" in a situation like that?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "now go to" appears many times in the Bible (both old and new testaments), also in Shakespeare, and it definitely is not profanity or telling someone to go elsewhere in any rude manner.  Keep in mind, the King James version of the Bible was translated into late middle English, so the phrase is likely a transliteration of some word or phrase in Hebrew, Aramaic or Greek.  Definitely, it's idiomatic.  Looking at the phrase in context, it probably equates to our contemporary "go for it", "get after it", "go do it", "do it" or "make it so".

Answer (score 0):

That phrase "Go to now" is used in the King James Bible,therefore I believe it does not indicate any profanity.

Answer (score 0):

I take it to mean ‘get outta here’ as in ‘get outta here with that nonsense’.  Which can be used when truly bothered by what was just said to you and you want that person to stop talking that nonsense immediately; or can be used in a facetious way (as in ‘get outta here, really?... tell me more!’.
This would also fit with the biblical version in James 4:13 “Go to now, ye that say, To day or to morrow we will go into such a city, and continue there a year, and buy and sell, and get gain: Whereas ye know not what shall be on the morrow. For what is your life? It is even a vapour, that appeareth for a little time, and then vanisheth away.“  Basically, this means to not think or speak in this manner.  Another way of saying it would be: ‘Dispense with these thoughts and manner of speech, for your own good.’

Answer (score 0):

It simply means calling someone’s attention to something. Simply substitute with the word ‘Come’ as if to get someone’s attention. In my culture we often use it this way.

Examples
“Come, what is your problem?”
“Come, you’d better make up your mind”

You can also substitute, “Hey!”

Answer (score 0):

- According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_to), the (now archaic meaning of) "*go to*" in your first example is:

  > Used imperatively to express protest or surprise; "*come, now!*".

  An example from Shakespeare's Macbeth is given there, as well:

  > [Act V, Scene I] Doctor: *Go to, go to. You have known what you should not.*

  This same use is corroborated by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-to):

  > - used interjectionally as an exhortation
  >   *and they said one to another, go to, let us make brick* [Genesis 11:3 (King James Version)]
  > - used interjectionally to express disapproval or disbelief
  >   [Followed by the same example from Shakespeare]

  Note that I left in the first meaning here—"*used interjectionally as an exhortation*"—because I believe it gives some insight into how the other use described can be interpreted: that sense of urgency could be the reason it became an interjection used as

  > - an exclamation expressing surprise, encouragement, etc

  Which [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/go-to) provides us.
- In your second sentence, the meaning of "*go to*" is literal, contemporary, and nothing like the meaning given above: Ivanhoe simply implores his knave to "*go to his place*".

Answer (score -2):

"Go to." This was in Romeo and Juliet... Tybalt sees Romeo at the party. He wants to kill him, rumble at the party. Father Capulet wants to know where he's "storming" and when Tybalt informs him the Romeo/Montagues are there, "I will not endure it."

"Go to. Go to...he will be endured."

Go to is almost like no. Get your mind right...slow your roll homeboi

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).